# Is $F(z) = \int_0^1\frac{dt}{t-z}$ where $z\in \mathbb{C}-[0,1]$ continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, continuity

I want to prove this function is continuous, I just know that $F(z) = \frac 12 \log \frac{(1-x)^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}+i\arctan \frac{y}{y^2+x^2−x}$

Comment: Well if you know that that's what $F$ equals, isn't your answer right there?

Comment: We have $F(z) - F(w) = (w-z)\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(t-z)(t-w)}{\rm d}z$. You can bound the integral for $z,w\not\in [0,1]$. Continuity follows from a simple $\epsilon-\delta$ argument without having to evaluate the integral directly.

Comment: I dont know if im correct, and i think my teacher wants me to prove it and i dont think that qualifies as a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

Let $F(z,t) = {1 \over t-z}$. Note that $F$ is uniformly continuous on any compact subset of
$(\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,1]) \times [0,1]$.

Pick some $z_0 \in \mathbb{C} \setminus [0,1]$, and choose some
$\delta >0$ such that $\overline{B}(z_0,\delta) \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus [0,1]$.

Now use uniform continuity to show that $f$ is continuous at $z_0$.